# Getting error: INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on integration part of a portfolio product where I got preinstalled database in SQL server 2008. I can’t insert or update the database directly I can do this by in API provided by this product’s developers.

Whenever I am inserting a particular trade type through API, I am getting error message –

> *The database 'usp_Financial_KernelComponents_Index_Insert_Batch_5'
>   command failed. The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_Fixings_id_Index_fixingsId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Portfolio_new", table "dbo.Financial_Shared_Fixings", column
>   'id'.*

How could I resolve this error OR what could be the possible reason of this error. Please suggest

Comment: @JW. It's probably the other way around: he's inserting a row with an ID that is *not* in the table.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep you are right! `:D` i guess i need to sleep now. haha Merry Christmas by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key constraint failure and error mesage when inserting values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213347/foreign-key-constraint-failure-and-error-mesage-when-inserting-values)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table.

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key constraint means that a value of a column or a group of columns must be present in a row of another table, usually as its primary key. Here is an example:

```
create table country (id int not null, name varchar(100))
create table city(id int not null, country_id int, name varchar(100))
```

If you set up a foreign key constraint on `city` requiring that `country_id` be present in the `country` table, an attempt to insert a `city` with an invalid `country_id` would result in a foreign key constraint violation.

In your case, the API probably takes a set of values, one of which must be an `ID` of some sort (or a secondary key through which an ID can be retrieved). When you pass an invalid `ID` to such an API, the foreign key constraint violation is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens whern you are trying to insert a value in foreign key column, which this value does not exists in it's parent table. for example you are trying to insert value X to CustomerId in Order table, which this value does not exists in Customer table. This error occurred because we need to have a good strategy for Referential Integrity. So the only you need to do, is to check your new values(which you are going to insert them into table) to find out that is there any value compromising this rule or not.

Please check the following question where you may find the same information about this error
[Foreign Key constraint failure and error message when inserting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213347/foreign-key-constraint-failure-and-error-mesage-when-inserting-values/33213983#33213983)

Comment: If this question is an exact duplicate of the linked question (aka the same answer can be used to solve both), then please flag it as a duplicate instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, please leave a complete answer instead of a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest of terms, you are inserting a "child" row *before* inserting the parent row.

At the instant you insert the child row, the child-parent (ie foreign key) constraint is violated - the child's parent appears to not exist.

To fix, reverse the order of insertion to be parent, then child(ren).

Answer (score -1):

Before inserting the record in the child table u need to insert in the parent table (i.e) the table where the reference column is reffered to